# AngularJS - How to access an array inside a nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, recursion

I have a recursive array in js:

```
[{
  type: 'cond',
  conditionId: 1,
  conditions: undefined
},
{
  type: 'cond',
  conditionId: 2,
  conditions: undefined
},
{
  type: 'group',
  conditionId: undefined,
  conditions: [{
      type: 'cond',
      conditionId: 3,
      conditions: undefined
    },
    {
      type: 'cond',
      conditionId: 4,
      conditions: undefined
    }]
}]
```

It is displayed in AngularJS using ng-repeat recursively with inline template:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="recursive_template.html">
<div> some logic </div>
        <div ng-repeat="cond in cond.conditions" ng-include="'recursive_template.html'"></div>
  <div> some more logic  </div>
</script>

<div ng-controller="EditRulesController">
  <div ng-repeat="cond in conditions" ng-include="'recursive_template.html'" class="row">
  </div>
</div>
```

Everything works fine.
Now I want to delete one item from inner *ng-repeat*. I can get the index of the item that I click on(to delete) with **$index**, also the object *cond* as parameter on *ng-click*. I can also access **$parent** but it points to the root of the object...

How to access the inner array without manually search through the whole *conditions* array recursively? Its strange that you can easily access the index of the inner array but not the actual array instance.

And any one advice on this issue? Thank you..

**EDIT 21/03/2016**

Before the accepted answer, the 'brute-force' version is implemented like this:

```
        $scope.deleteConditionClick = function (id) {
            deleteCondition($scope.conditions, id);
        };

        function deleteCondition(conditions, id) {

            var conds = conditions;
            if (conds) {
                for (var i = 0; i < conds.length; i++) {
                    if (conds[i].type === 'cond') {
                        if (conds[i].conditionId === id) {
                            conds.splice(i, 1);
                            return true;
                        }
                    } else if (conds[i].type === 'group') {

                        deleteCondition(conds[i].conditions, id);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I hope it will help others with similar problem.

Comment: Are you not able to access it as cond.conditions.type, cond.conditions.conditionId ?

Comment: `$parent.$parent` - `ngInclude` is creating *another* scope between your parent repeat and your child repeat.

Comment: `$parent.$parent` gave me the controller scope, so the root of the array again.

Comment: @CoderJohn : I can access it, but I want to delete it and I need the containing array to delete from. The example is just two levels deep, imagine if there are 10 levels nested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting you delete action to be `ng-click="cond=undefined"`? This would empty the deleted condition. You could then use ng-show/ng-if to control visibility in the view.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I grab items with multiple indexes:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in outerArray" ng-init="outerIndex = $index">
  <div ng-repeat="y in innerArray">
    {{ innerArray[outerIndex] }}
  </div>
</div>
```

I think this is what you were asking? I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, I like this. The problem is that my object can be nested any level, not just 2. In that case a list of outer indexes is needed, which is again hard to manage.

Comment: Did @michaelbinks' solution fix the issue or should I propose something else?

Comment: Yes, it is a very good workaround, but I'm curious if you have any other ideas :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the parent array and the object as parameters (eg.: `ng-click="delete(conditions, cond)`") and use `.indexOf()` function  to find the index of the object (eg. `$scope.delete = function(conditions, cond){index = conditions.indexOf(cond)...}`)

Comment: Yes, I tried this, but it gives me the root of the array because there is a `$scope.conditions` in controller. I also tried to rename that variable to have different name from inner arrays. Unfortunately it doesn't work.